# Python list comprehension returns nested list

Tags: python, file, list-comprehension, os.walk

I built this little program to simulate 2 libraries I want to compare files with.

The code is this:

```
import os

path = "C:\Users\\nelson\Desktop\Lib Check"

pc_path = os.path.join(path, "pc")
phone_path = os.path.join(path, "phone")

pc_lib = [filename for path, dirname, filename in os.walk(pc_path)]

print pc_lib
```

it returns

```
[['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt', '4.txt', '5.txt', '6.txt', '8.txt', '9.txt']]
```

everything is fine except for the fact that the results are in a nested list. Why?

The only way I can stop this is by using

```
pc_lib = []
for path, dirname, filename in os.walk(pc_path):
    pc_lib.extend(filename)
```

Comment: just for further reference, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) is a neat way of flattening lists in Python.

Answer (score 1):

filename is a list of files (the name you've used is not intuitive), so the results are expected

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('my/home/directory'):
     print(files)
#['close_button.gif', 'close_button_red.gif'], 
#['toolbar.js']
```

`extend` *unwraps* the argument `list` and appends the resulting elements to the `list` that made the call

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of filenames, I would suggest:

```
[os.path.join(path, filename) 
 for path, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(pc_path)
 for filename in filenames]
```

Comment: This would throw a `NameError`: `filenames` is not defined. `for filename in filenames` should come last

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk(path)` returns an iterator over tuples of `(root, dirs, files)`.

Where

- `root` is the path of the current directory relative to the argument of `os.walk`
- `dirs` is a `list` of all the subdirectories in the current directory
- `files` is a `list` of all normal files in the current directory

If you want a flat list of all files in a filesystem tree, use:

```
pc_lib = [
    filename for _, _, files in os.walk(pc_path)
    for filename in files
]
```

You probably want to retain the absolute path, to get thos use:

```
pc_lib = [
    os.path.join(root, filename)
    for root, _, files in os.walk(pc_path)
    for filename in files
]
```